# Background Running Process logging

Tags: java, logging, background-process, nohup

Am having a java program which listens to **ApacheMQ** and runs in background and am using Linux Server. Here I have used `System.out.println()` for my logging andI have to transfer those contents to a file.

Is it possible, am completely novice to this and Whether I have to use **Log4J** or **nohup** to write this `sysout()` value to a file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you observe, using nohup you get out redirected to a file. More generally, a linux process can have its output redirected to a file

```
 myApp > someFile.log
```

or maybe better appended to a file

```
 myApp >> someFile.log
```

so that when you restart you don't lose previous output.

Alternatively, as you indicate, you can put the app in charge of choosing where to write, and then using a library such as Log4j instead of System.out is very helpful.

I would use **both** approches: I recommend using some such logging library in any serious application, and I would start my application from a script that ensures that all output is captured in log files, this ensures that should you use some library code that writes to a stdout or stderr that the output is kept. I like to create output files whose names include date and time that the app was started, this makes it easier to find particular output.

Comment: Mails sending from there are getting 5minutes to send a mail. I dont know previously its faster.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("my-output.txt");

// write text.
out.println("hello world");

// when finished.
out.close();
```

Just `replace` `System.out` with `out`

I am surprised you can use JMS but don't know how to work out how to write to a file.

Comment: Sorry its not coded by me. Its very urgent one because senior too left and mailing system is very badly slow. I need a fast approach now then have to look at JMS. Thanks Peter.